# I can't see any edit revisions!

Tags: bug, android-app, revisions-list

Using Android app 1.0.59

The button to see revisions seems to be broken in the Android app. The app does nothing when I click the "Edited " words (which should bring me to a page with revisions).

My internet connection is perfect.

The app is not lagging.

Is it possible to fix this bug?

Comment: Can't be a bug since it was never implemented in the android app.

Comment: That's fast... :P it has never been implemented!?